# C - Array of structs function pointer

Tags: c, function, pointers, struct

The first program below calls a function using a pointer successfully. I am now trying to get the same mechanism to work using an array of structs. The last line (commented out) will not work, and I do not see any differences. What am I doing wrong?

Is it possible I have the wrong format for this line in the second program?

> *void (*func_ptr)(struct book, int) = printBook;*
> I used this format: `<ret type> (<*varname>) (<parm type>, <parm type>,...) = function`

**This works...**

```
// C call function using pointer
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void func(int a)  {   // normal function
  printf("Value of a is %d\n", a);
}

int main() {
  void (*func_ptr)(int) = func;         // assign ptr to func address
  func_ptr(10); // call func
  return 0;
}
```

**This does not work...**

```
// Looks the same but does not work
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// data structure
struct book {                          // struct data
  int     book_id;                     // book id
  int     (*prtFunc) ( struct book  ); // eventually, addr of print function
  char    title[50];                   // book title
  char    author[50];                  // book author
};

struct book arBookList[10];

void printBook ( struct book arBookList[], int id ) {           // test struct access
  printf ( "book_id       : %d\n", arBookList[id].book_id );    
  printf ( "func addr     : %p\n", arBookList[id].prtFunc );    // eventually this will call function
  printf ( "title         : %s\n", arBookList[id].title   );    // string data test
  printf ( "author        : %s\n", arBookList[id].author  );    // string
  printf ( "\n" );
}

int main (  ) {

  arBookList[0].book_id =  0 ;
  arBookList[0].prtFunc = printBook;
  strcpy ( arBookList[0].title, "This Little Piggy" );
  strcpy ( arBookList[0].author, "Bad Wolf" );
  printBook (arBookList, 0 );                             // show data using function call

  arBookList[1].book_id =  1 ;
  arBookList[1].prtFunc = printBook;
  strcpy ( arBookList[1].title, "Mary Had a Lamb" );
  strcpy ( arBookList[1].author, "Snow Fleece" );
  printBook (arBookList, 1 );                             // show data using function call

  // call function using pointer
  void (*func_ptr)(struct book, int) = printBook;         // assign ptr to func address
 
  func_ptr (arBookList, 1 );                              // <--- does not work, why ???
  // commenting out the above line compiles ok 
  // but it looks ok to me except for different call parameters

  return 0;
}
```

**For future reference:** With 'O's corrected listing below I reached my final goal which was to be able to call a saved function pointer in struct to call a function (in this case printBook) like this: `arBookList[1].prtFunc (arBookList, 1 );`

Comment: What error does your compiler gives you? That should be a clue.

Comment: parameters don't match the definition

Comment: A `struct book` is not the same thing as a `struct book *`.  The function expects the latter, but your function pointer's type indicates that the pointed-to function expects the former.  The call through the pointer has the correct argument types for the actual function, but not for the function pointer.

Comment: I am not sure what line you are referring to? What line needs changing to struct book *

Comment: The function pointer `int (*prtFunc) (struct book);` does not match the function which has the signature `void printBook (struct book arBookList[], int id)`

Comment: @ted, that line (var) is never used (place holder), I have not crossed that bride yet.

Comment: @jwzumwalt You crossed it when you did `arBookList[1].prtFunc = printBook;`  and tried to assign an incompatible function pointer to `prtFunc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `struct book` you have `prtFunc` declared as

```
    int (*prtFunc)(struct book);  // eventually, addr of print function
```

And in `main` you have error on

```
    arBookList[0].prtFunc = printBook;
```

But `printBook` is

```
void printBook(struct book arBookList[], int id)
```

So the acual parameters does not match the declaration.

#### another issue

A bit *off-topic* but if the function is the same for all books its address should not be replicated in every `book` in the array.

#### Example: using a collection instead of an array

```
typedef struct
{                     // struct data
    int  book_id;     // book id
    char title[50];   // book title
    char author[50];  // book author
} Book; // a single book

typedef struct
{
    size_t limit;  // capacity
    size_t size;   // actual size
    Book   book_list[10];
    int (*print_book)(Book*);
} Books; // a collection
```

This way we have a **collection** `Books` that has a `size` and `limit`. And also a pointer to a function that prints a single book. And the books are inside the `struct` so you can use it as a whole.

Your test collection can be declared in a modern way as

```
    Books coll = {
        .limit = 10,
        .size  = 2,
        .book[0] =
            {.id     = 42,
             .title  = "This Little Piggy",
             .author = "Bad Wolf"},
        .book[1] =
            {.id     = 4242,
             .title  = "Mary Had a Lamb",
             .author = "Snow Fleece"},
        .print_book =
            printBook  // this function prints a book
    };
```

This is easier to read and test.

#### a version of `print_book`

```
void print_book(Book* book)
{
    printf(
        "\
    book_id       : %d\n\
    title         : %s\n\
    author        : %s\n\
\n",
        book->id, book->title, book->author);
};
```

A single `printf` (or `puts`) is way more faster and easier to read and type

#### printing all books

It can be convenient to have a function to print the complete `Books` struct:

```
int print_all(Books* col)
{
    if (col == NULL) return -1;
    printf(
        "    there are %llu of %llu books\n\n", col->size,
        col->limit);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < col->size; i += 1)
        col->print_book(&col->book[i]);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
};
```

Since it uses the embedded pointer in the `Books` struct it is easy to change style just by changing the pointer inside the struct

#### using the 2 functions

```
    coll.print_book(&coll.book[0]);
    print_book(&coll.book[1]);
   // print all
    printf("test: print the collection\n\n");
    print_all(&coll);
```

here we call `print_book` to print each book, by name and by reference using the pointer inside collection. Then the collection is printed.

#### A complete example

```
// Looks the same but does not work
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct
{                     // struct data
    int  id;          // book id
    char title[50];   // book title
    char author[50];  // book author
} Book;               // a single book

typedef struct
{
    size_t limit;  // capacity
    size_t size;   // actual size
    Book   book[10];
    void (*print_book)(Book*);
} Books;                          // a collection

void print_book(Book* book);      // single book
void print_book_alt(Book* book);  // single book,one line
int  print_all(Books*);           // collection

int main(void)
{
    Books coll = {
        .limit = 10,
        .size  = 2,
        .book[0] =
            {.id     = 42,
             .title  = "This Little Piggy",
             .author = "Bad Wolf"},
        .book[1] =
            {.id     = 4242,
             .title  = "Mary Had a Lamb",
             .author = "Snow Fleece"},
        .print_book =
            print_book  // this function prints a book
    };

    coll.print_book(&coll.book[0]);
    print_book(&coll.book[1]);
    // print all
    printf("test: print the collection\n\n");
    print_all(&coll);
    // test alternate print f.
    printf("test: alternate print\n\n");
    print_book_alt(&coll.book[0]);
    print_book_alt(&coll.book[1]);
    // adds a new book
    Book other = {
        .id     = 17,
        .title  = "My time with Ms. Lane",
        .author = "Super Man"};
    printf("\ntest: new book\n\n");
    print_book_alt(&other);
    // updates collection
    coll.book[2] = other;
    coll.size += 1;
    print_all(&coll);
    // changes printing
    coll.print_book = print_book_alt;
    printf("\ntest: print the collection again\n\n");
    print_all(&coll);
    return 0;
}

void print_book(Book* book)
{
    printf(
        "\
    book_id       : %d\n\
    title         : %s\n\
    author        : %s\n\
\n",
        book->id, book->title, book->author);
};

int print_all(Books* col)
{
    if (col == NULL) return -1;
    printf(
        "    there are %llu of %llu books\n\n", col->size,
        col->limit);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < col->size; i += 1)
        col->print_book(&col->book[i]);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
};

void print_book_alt(Book* book)
{
    printf(
        "%8d, \"%s\", [%s]\n", book->id, book->title,
        book->author);
}
```

#### the output of the example

```
    book_id       : 42
    title         : This Little Piggy
    author        : Bad Wolf

    book_id       : 4242
    title         : Mary Had a Lamb
    author        : Snow Fleece

test: print the collection

    there are 2 of 10 books

    book_id       : 42
    title         : This Little Piggy
    author        : Bad Wolf

    book_id       : 4242
    title         : Mary Had a Lamb
    author        : Snow Fleece


test: alternate print

      42, "This Little Piggy", [Bad Wolf]
    4242, "Mary Had a Lamb", [Snow Fleece]

test: new book

      17, "My time with Ms. Lane", [Super Man]
    there are 3 of 10 books

    book_id       : 42
    title         : This Little Piggy
    author        : Bad Wolf

    book_id       : 4242
    title         : Mary Had a Lamb
    author        : Snow Fleece

    book_id       : 17
    title         : My time with Ms. Lane
    author        : Super Man



test: print the collection again

    there are 3 of 10 books

      42, "This Little Piggy", [Bad Wolf]
    4242, "Mary Had a Lamb", [Snow Fleece]
      17, "My time with Ms. Lane", [Super Man]
```

In this example

- the printing function is called twice, one by name and other using the pointer in `Books`
- a book is added to the collection
- an alternate printing function is added
- the function pointer inside `Books` is changed
- the collection is again printed

### C with classes: turning the `Container` generic using function pointers

Here is the `struct` for the *collection* in the previous example:

```
typedef struct
{
    size_t limit;  // capacity
    size_t size;   // actual size
    Book   book_list[10];
    int (*print_book)(Book*);
} Books; // a collection
```

It solves many things, since it can be treated as a whole and encapsulates the current and total size limits.

But:

- if `Book` allocates memory there is no way to free it.
- The *collecion's* items are themselves inside the `struct`

  - resize is difficult
  - delete an item is difficult
- It is the same file so a change in the container **OR** in the items triggers a change in the same code

> It would be better to have the code for the container independent from the item's code.

#### Example: a more generic container

Sure it is a list of items. But could be a linked list, a set, a queue, an array... `C++` calls it a *container*. `java` and others call them *collection*.

Consider

```
typedef struct
{
    size_t limit;             // capacity
    size_t size;              // actual size
    void** item;              // an array of pointers to items
    void* (*copy)(void*);     // copy
    void* (*destroy)(void*);  // destructor
    int (*show)(void*);       // print
} Container;                  // a collection
```

Now we have an array of pointers to items and:

- it is easy to resize: we have just references to the item
- we have no reference to the actual definition of the item
- we know how to copy an item in order to insert it into the container
- we know how to destroy an item when destroying the container or managing the container's contents.
- we know how to show one item at the screen

But the container have no idea about its actual contents: it is the user of the container that produces the code, and the container's just saves the function pointers.

**There is no need to even recompile the code for `container.c`**

```
> now we can implement the container code with no mention to the items: a container can contain anything: books, SDL screens, SDL renderers, invoices, movie tickets...
```

A minimum set of functions:

```
Container* ctn_create(
  size_t, void* (*copy)(void*), void* (*destroy)(void*),
  int (*show)(void*));
Container* ctn_destroy(Container*);
int        ctn_insert(void*, Container*);
int        ctn_show(Container*);
```

This is the mininum to write an example, like this one down here.

#### `Book` as an `Item` in `item.h`

```
#pragma once
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{                   // struct data
    size_t id;      // book id
    char*  title;   // book title
    char*  author;  // book author
    size_t n_pages;   
} Book;             // a single book

int   print_book(void*);
int   print_book_alt(void*);  // one liner
void* copy_book(void*);
void* create_book(void);
void* delete_book(void*);
```

A change in container code does not lead to a change in the item code, thanks to the function pointers. In `C++` they would be called *copy constructor*, *destructor* and *operator << overload* of `Item`.

#### Implementation: `Book`

#### item.h

```
#pragma once
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{                   // struct data
    size_t id;      // book id
    char*  title;   // book title
    char*  author;  // book author
    size_t n_pages;   
} Book;             // a single book

int   print_book(void*);
int   print_book_alt(void*);  // one liner
void* copy_book(void*);
void* create_book(void);
void* delete_book(void*);
```

The functions now accept and return `void`, but there is a definition for `Book` so all of them can cast the pointers as needed. This is the same approach used in `qsort` from `stdlib` for example, since ever. Like  *callbacks* in `java` or `javascript`.

Note that now `Book` uses pointers to `title` and `author` and has a new field for # of pages. So memory is allocated to the exact size needed, instead of the fixed arrays of the first example.

Problem is that now to destroy a container the code has to know how to free these fields and the `Book` itself. Here is the use )and need) for a *callback*, a function pointer.

#### `item.c` a simple implementation

```
#include "item.h"

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void* copy_book(void* book)
{
    if (book == NULL) return NULL;
    Book* one     = (Book*)book;
    Book* other   = (void*)malloc(sizeof(Book));
    other->id     = one->id;
    other->author = malloc(1 + sizeof(one->author));
    strcpy(other->author, one->author);
    other->title = malloc(1 + sizeof(one->title));
    strcpy(other->title, one->title);
    other->n_pages = one->n_pages;
    return (void*)other;
};

void* create_book(void)
{
    static size_t id         = 1000;
    char          author[40] = {0};
    char          title[40]  = {0};
    Book*         one        = (void*)malloc(sizeof(Book));

    sprintf(&author[0], "Author %llu", id);
    one->author = malloc(1 + strlen(author));
    strcpy(one->author, author);

    sprintf(&title[0], "Title %llu", id);
    one->title = malloc(1 + strlen(title));
    strcpy(one->title, title);

    one->id      = id++;
    one->n_pages = 200 + rand() % 155;
    return (void*) one;
};

void* delete_book(void* book)
{
    if (book == NULL) return NULL;
    Book* one = (Book*)book;
    free(one->author);
    free(one->title);
    free(one);  // simple, void does not allocate
    return NULL;
}

int print_book(void* book)
{
    if (book == NULL) return 0;
    Book* one = (Book*)book;
    printf(
        "\
    Book ID       : %llu\n\
    title         : %s [%llu pages]\n\
    author        : %s\n\
\n",
        one->id, one->title, one->n_pages, one->author);
    return 0;
};

int print_book_alt(void* book)
{
    if (book == NULL) return 0;
    Book* one = (Book*)book;
    printf(
        "%8llu, \"%s [%llu pages]\", [%s]\n", one->id,
        one->title, one->n_pages, one->author);
    return 0;
}
```

No reference to `Container`: just includes `item.h` to get `Book` and function prototypes.

Note the addition of `create_book()`, a handy *factory function* that generates a new book for each time it is called. This way is easy to test with any number of items with no input files.

#### Code for a generic `Container`

Note that the container does no even include `item.h`

#### `container.h`

```
#pragma once
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct
{
    size_t limit;             // capacity
    size_t size;              // actual size
    void** item;              // an array of pointers to items
    void* (*copy)(void*);     // copy
    void* (*destroy)(void*);  // destructor
    int (*show)(void*);       // print
} Container;                  // a collection

Container* ctn_create(
    size_t, void* (*copy)(void*), void* (*destroy)(void*),
    int (*show)(void*));
Container* ctn_destroy(Container*);
int        ctn_insert(void*, Container*);
int        ctn_show(Container*);
```

And the `Container` is now an array of pointers to items. Any item, since the user when calling `ctn_create()` passes the addresses of the functions.

This way a program can easily manage an array of items, even of diferent ones.

#### `container.c`

```
#pragma once
#include "container.h"

Container* ctn_create(
    size_t size, void* (*copy)(void*),
    void* (*destroy)(void*), int (*show)(void*))
{
    Container* ctn =
        (Container*)malloc(sizeof(Container) * size);
    if (ctn == NULL) return NULL;
    ctn->limit = size;  // limit
    ctn->size  = 0;     // now empty, of course
    ctn->item = (void**)malloc(size * sizeof(void*));
    if (ctn->item == NULL)
    {  // could not allocate
        free(ctn);
        return NULL;
    }
    ctn->copy    = copy;
    ctn->destroy = destroy;
    ctn->show    = show;
    return ctn;
}

Container* ctn_destroy(Container* ctn)
{  // to destroy a container we need to know how to
    // delete the voids: they can allocate memory
    if (ctn == NULL) return NULL;
    for (size_t ix = 0; ix < ctn->size; ix += 1)
        ctn->destroy(ctn->item[ix]);
    return NULL;
}

int ctn_insert(void* item, Container* ctn)
{  // it is not wise to insert just a pointer
    // that can be free'd elsewhere:
    // it must be a copy. But an void can allocate
    // memory so we need to rely on user supplied
    // method
    if (item == NULL) return -1;       // no void
    if (ctn == NULL) return -2;        // no container
    if (ctn->size == ctn->limit)
        return -3;                     // container full
    if (ctn->copy == NULL) return -4;  // no copy function
    ctn->item[ctn->size] = ctn->copy(item);
    if (ctn->item[ctn->size] == NULL)
        return -5;  // error on copy
    ctn->size += 1;
    return 0;
}

int ctn_show(Container* col)
{
    if (col == NULL) return -1;
    printf(
        "    there are %llu of %llu items\n\n", col->size,
        col->limit);
    if (col->show == NULL) return -1;  // no show function
    for (size_t i = 0; i < col->size; i += 1)
        col->show(col->item[i]);
    printf("[end of listing]\n");
    return 0;
}
```

#### `main.c` for a simple test

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "container.h"
#include "item.h"

int main(void)
{
    const int  test_size = 6;
    Container* books =
        ctn_create(30, copy_book, delete_book, print_book);
    for (size_t id = 1; id <= test_size; id += 1)
    {
        Book* newb = create_book();
        ctn_insert(newb, books);
        delete_book(newb);
    };
    ctn_show(books);
    printf(
        "\n\t***** now print again, using new layout\n\n");
    books->show = print_book_alt;
    ctn_show(books);             // now using _alt
    books = ctn_destroy(books);  // delete all
    ctn_show(books);             // now empty
    return 0;
}
```

Note 1:

```
    ctn_show(books);
    printf(
        "\n\t***** now print again, using new layout\n\n");
    books->show = print_book_alt;
    ctn_show(books);             // now using _alt
```

The point of using `books->show` here is that it encapsulates behavior, as an object in `Python` or `java` or `C++`: by changing this, the next call to `cnt_show` inherits the new print layout: see the program output below

Note 2:

```
    ctn_show(books);             // now using _alt
    books = ctn_destroy(books);  // delete all
    ctn_show(books);             // now empty
```

By returning `NULL` from `cnt_destroy` the pointer of the container is invalidaded in the same line of code: no way to have an invalid pointer. This is great, so the call to `ctn->show` on the next line will not get the pointer of a container already deleted.

#### output for the example

```
    there are 6 of 30 items

    Book ID       : 1000
    title         : Title 1000 [241 pages]
    author        : Author 1000

    Book ID       : 1001
    title         : Title 1001 [222 pages]
    author        : Author 1001

    Book ID       : 1002
    title         : Title 1002 [334 pages]
    author        : Author 1002

    Book ID       : 1003
    title         : Title 1003 [350 pages]
    author        : Author 1003

    Book ID       : 1004
    title         : Title 1004 [304 pages]
    author        : Author 1004

    Book ID       : 1005
    title         : Title 1005 [269 pages]
    author        : Author 1005

[end of listing]

        ***** now print again, using new layout

    there are 6 of 30 items

    1000, "Title 1000 [241 pages]", [Author 1000]
    1001, "Title 1001 [222 pages]", [Author 1001]
    1002, "Title 1002 [334 pages]", [Author 1002]
    1003, "Title 1003 [350 pages]", [Author 1003]
    1004, "Title 1004 [304 pages]", [Author 1004]
    1005, "Title 1005 [269 pages]", [Author 1005]
[end of listing]
```

Code is on https://github.com/ARFNeto-CH/soc23-0720-example

Comment: Thanks, I will examine this closely. I caused a lot of confusion with the "arBookList[0].prtFunc = printBook;" This program is a proof of concept for a SDL graphics program I am writing. The actual program is to save button information where each button will call a unique handler routine. I am a retired programmer and never worked much with pointers or structs so this is all very new and different. I have kept several thousand example routines over the years and this was an area I was lacking. I also have a large book library but none had examples. This will be added to my reference.

Comment: I will add a few handlers to this example in the next days so you will have a more complete set. Anyway take a look at the `print_book` pointer in the example as a handler for printing. Hope it helps.

Comment: I spent the after noon looking and reformatting for my notes. It gave me good ideas on old problems like keeping track of num of elements. I always liked the way Pascal kept the array size at index[0]. This accomplishes the same thing. I think I will try it for my buttons and I may completely adopt it. At first it looked more cluttered but I think I am just not used to it. I looked for a way on Stack Overflow to communicate privately but did not find a way. I was an accomplished C programmer (really jack-of-all-trades) 35 years ago. Never an expert. I did sys admin, sql db, bash script, etc.

Comment: Pascal keeps the array size at index `0` but it is a single info. _Containers_, as called in `C++`, or _collections_ as called in java, keep track of more things, _metadata_ that can include --- as in the `C` code I wrote --- max size, actual size and **methods**, user defined functions embedded within the `struct`, or `class`, or `object`, I believe that these **methods** are the event handlers you are about to implement

Comment: I finally spent several hours with your code and see all the advantages. I decided to call what you refer to as "collections" (the whole db)  as a "list". I have also decided to adopt your code. I look forward to seeing what else you add!  :-)

Comment: I will add a list then. It may help. SO does not like to be seen as a forum or contact network, so contact info is not enforced by any means. I am surprised by this thread not being moved to chat yet (chat is somewhat ok for SO, but I never used it). Anyway I will let my e-mail at the revised example.

Comment: @jwzumwalt I have just added two examples using function pointers to create a more generic container, and posted on `Github` for ease access. Just copy and paste from the original example but more on the `C++/java` way. With your decades long experience you will see ways to use something like this. HIH

Comment: I looked on git hub for your email but did not find it. I am at jwzumwalt@gmail.com please contact me.

Comment: I added a new example of a generic container so you can see a complete example of using function pointers. And use it everywhere.

Answer (score 4):

For function pointer takes wrong parameter. You pass pointer and it is expecting the struct.

The corrected program:

```
struct book {                          // struct data
  int     book_id;                     // book id
  void     (*prtFunc) (struct book  *, int); // eventually, addr of print function
  char    title[50];                   // book title
  char    author[50];                  // book author
};

struct book arBookList[10];

void printBook ( struct book *arBookList, int id ) {           // test struct access
  printf ( "book_id       : %d\n", arBookList[id].book_id );    
  printf ( "func addr     : %p\n", arBookList[id].prtFunc );    // eventually this will call function
  printf ( "title         : %s\n", arBookList[id].title   );    // string data test
  printf ( "author        : %s\n", arBookList[id].author  );    // string
  printf ( "\n" );
}

int main (  ) {

  arBookList[0].book_id =  0 ;
  arBookList[0].prtFunc = printBook;
  strcpy ( arBookList[0].title, "This Little Piggy" );
  strcpy ( arBookList[0].author, "Bad Wolf" );
  printBook (arBookList, 0 );                             // show data using function call

  arBookList[1].book_id =  1 ;
  arBookList[1].prtFunc = printBook;
  strcpy ( arBookList[1].title, "Mary Had a Lamb" );
  strcpy ( arBookList[1].author, "Snow Fleece" );
  printBook (arBookList, 1 );                             // show data using function call

  // call function using pointer
  void (*func_ptr)(struct book *, int) = printBook;         // assign ptr to func address
 
  func_ptr (arBookList, 1 );                              // <--- does not work, why ???
  // commenting out the above line compiles ok 
  // but it looks ok to me except for different call parameters

  return 0;
}
```

Also your function pointer in the struct had a wrong type.

https://godbolt.org/z/5E1E8v7j3

Comment: Thanks, I had tried every variation of pointer in  the call param but had no idea I needed a pointer in the functions param because I thought an array name WAS an addr already? :-(

Comment: @jwzumwalt but the function was execting the structure itself not the pointer to it. When the function takes the structure or union when whole structure is passed as parameter, not releference to it. Structure is not an array!!

Comment: GREAT! now  the struct has the function to call  arBookList[1].prtFunc (arBookList, 1 ); as was my goal.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I will have to think about it a few hours - I will eventually see my error. It sometimes takes me awhile for things to click. Thx for the quick help.

Comment: An array name is an address: the address of the starting of the array in memory. The function you declared in the `struct` expects `(struct book  *, int)` as parameters. But in the call you have `struct book[10], const int` and this is another thing.

Comment: Thanks, you have been very helpful. I had searched far and wide for web examples before posting but could not find any because I was using the wrong search term. With the information you have provided I was able to find other examples. While I still don't quit understand why structs appear to be the only array calls with "*" it will eventually sink in.